# Java Regex: Grouping consecutive 1 or 0 in a binary string

Tags: java, regex

I want to capture all the consecutive groups in a binary string

```
1000011100001100111100001
```

should give me

```
1
0000
111
0000
11
00
1111
0000
1
```

I have made `([1?|0?]+)` regex in my java application to group the consequential 1 or 0 in the string like `10000111000011`. 
But when I run it in my code, **there is nothing in the console printed:**

```
String name ="10000111000011";
    regex("(\\[1?|0?]+)" ,name);

    public static void regex(String regex, String searchedString) {

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher regexMatcher = pattern.matcher(searchedString);
        while (regexMatcher.find()) 
            if (regexMatcher.group().length() > 0)
                System.out.println(regexMatcher.group());
    }
```

To avoid syntax error in the runtime of regex, I have changed the `([1?|0?]+)` to the `(\\[1?|0?]+)`

**Why there is no group based on regex?**

Comment: Please explain why you downvoted this question?

Comment: i edited my question, I know. it just consider all as one group. But u shouldn't downvote me because of it :(

Comment: Next time please provide sample input _and_ output from the start :)

Comment: Yes, sure. I just thought, the tester site accepts it, but i didn't noticed it accepted it as only one group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First - just as an explanation - your regex *defines* a character class (`[` ... `]`) that matches any of the characters `1`, `?`, `|` or `0` one or more times (`+`). I think you mean to have `(` ... `)` in it, among other things, which would make the `|` an alternation lazy matching a `0` or a `1`. But that's not either what you want (I think ;).

Now, the solution might be this:

```
([01])\1*
```

which matches a `0` or a `1`, and captures it. Then it matches any number of the same digit (`\1` is a back reference to what ever is captured in the first capture group - in this case the `0` or the `1`) any number of times.

[Check it out at ideone](http://ideone.com/FXpQx3).

Comment: Your regex also, does not print anything **(\\[01])\1**

Comment: Check the example added.

Comment: And note that the **regex** is `([01])\1*`. As a java string that is `"([01])\\1*"`.

Comment: Perfect, can you explain the **\1** part in your regex? what does it try to say?

Comment: Added explanation to answer.

Comment: This expression only captures the first digit in any sequence of 0's and 1's. Is that the desired output? From the question I read that you want all of the digit to get captured.

Comment: @Quota Correct, it **captures** the first digit. But if you check the OP's example, the full match is used  - `regexMatcher.group()` (No number as parameter to `group` gives the complete match).

Comment: And I'd like to thank http://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen for revenge-down-voting this answer ;)

Comment: @ClasG Thanks, didn't pay attention to that `matcher.group()`. For the sake of simplicity, I would probably prefere `(0+|1+)` over your back reference regexp as I, too, had to look up what that meant... :)

Comment: @Quota That may be true - it might be simpler to understand. And in that  case you may even simplify it further by removing the capturing group - `0+|1+` which makes it (much) more efficient. The one I've given can easily be modified for other applications though (like matching ranges of letters `(\w)\1*`). But that's not really in the scope, so...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
(1+|0+)
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/RHIu0r/9)

Sample Code:

```
    final String regex = "(1+|0+)";
    final String string = "10000111000011\n"
            + "11001111110011";

    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE | Pattern.MULTILINE);
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

    while (matcher.find()) {

                System.out.println("Group " + 1 + ": " + matcher.group(1));


    }
```